# 'BCEWithLogitsLoss' object has no attribute 'backward' error PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, text-classification, loss-function, backpropagation, bert-language-model

I'm trying to fine-tune the Bert model i.e., bert-base-uncased for a text classification task. I'm getting a strange error while calling the backward() on loss, which is as follows

**torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'BCEWithLogitsLoss' object has no attribute 'backward'.**

I can't find any syntax error and also checked the inputs(outputs and targets) to the loss function i.e, nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(outputs, targets) and I found then to be in the correct format. I don't know what is causing this error. I would be great if any of you could help me with this......thanks in advance :)

Here is the code

'''def train_loop_fn(data_loader, model, optimizer, device, scheduler = None):
model.train()
for bi, d in enumerate(data_loader):
ids = d["ids"]
mask = d["mask"]
token_type_ids = d["token_type_ids"]
targets = d["targets"]

```
    ids = ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
    mask = mask.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
    token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
    targets = targets.to(device, dtype=torch.float)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(ids=ids, mask = mask, token_type_ids = token_type_ids)
    outputs = outputs.reshape(1)
    print("here is the outputs")
    print(outputs)
    print("here is the targets")
    print(targets)
    loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(outputs, targets)
    print("this is the loss")
    print(loss)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if scheduler is not None:
        scheduler.step()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```py
loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(outputs, targets)
```

or better this way:

```py
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in dataloader:
        ...
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        ...
```

Also, please go through the docs before posting a question. The PyTorch docs provide a simple example of how to use. Here is an example from torch's website:

[image]